# Output from a curl command using system.run

Tags: zabbix

I have an active Zabbix item running a curl command on my server.

Key:
`system.run[curl http://localhost:8080/mypage]`

When I run this curl command manually the output is a number, but in Zabbix I get:

Output:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100     3  100     3    0     0    434      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   500
146
```

The only thing I want to see is the '146' at the end, can I stop Zabbix from outputting the other information.

Preferably I would like the data type to be numeric - decimal but I'm having to set it to text for the item to work. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-s` (`--silent`) parameter to `curl`, like so:

```
system.run[curl -s http://localhost:8080/mypage]
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, and this allows me to use a numeric type as well

Comment: how can I call it on zabbix server?

Comment: You could probably wrap that `curl` invocation into a script and then use [external checks](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external).